# How to split a feature and save back to database?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis-1.5

How to split/cut a polygon through OpenLayers split method and same editing save to the PostGIS?

Comment: are you going through geoserver or directly to postgis?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenLayer's Split control](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Split-js.html) is straight forward. You pass it a layer in the contructor and the control will split it.

If your layer has ONE feature and you split it using the control you will end up with TWO features in the layer.

Once youre ready to save to PostGIS, you can write those features to a number of different formats WKT, KML, GML, etc. And pass that to your backend webservice wether it be a GeoServer WFS-T or a PHP, C# or other back-end handler/service that will save the features to your postGIS database.

[Click here for an OpenLayers 2 Split Feature Example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/split-feature.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can split or cut your polygon at server side by means of postgis function. in postgis ST_Split function makes what you want. this function is opposite of ST_Union...

following example has taken from postgis api doc. :

```
SELECT ST_Split(circle, line)
FROM (SELECT 
    ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(10, 10),ST_MakePoint(190, 190)) As line,
    ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'), 50) As circle) As foo;
```

and another solution for this is that you can check [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). it has lots of feature with Geometry Operations.

some example of operation:

```
contains, within
covers, coveredBy
intersects, disjoint
crosses
overlaps
touches
equals
```